# how to increase the size of image so that it is visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to increase the size of image or icon  .It is not visible .
I take icon from this link
http://ionicons.com/ and this one **ion-chevron-left**

here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJRJLj

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
  <div class="buttons">
    <i class='icon ion-chevron-left'></i>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>

</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
<div class="button-bar">
  <a class="button">First</a>
  <a class="button">Second</a>
  <a class="button">Third</a>
  <a class="button">fourth</a>
</div></ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The icon seems visible!

Comment: got the answer..@zee give answer

Comment: but your statement is wrong, unless something else is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `font-size`.

```
<i style="font-size:50px;" class='icon ion-chevron-left'></i>
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

As @zee told (+1 for his reply) , you have to use `font-size` property for ionicons (& for exemple font-awesomes) to increase size.

I just wanted to complete his answer saying that as those packages are fonts, all css properties that affects fonts are available for thoses icons , such as `font-color`